# Unable to find node_modules on client side in angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node-modules

I am trying to load a non-angular library inside my angular 1 app.

index.html has following script:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/@mylib/index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="../bower_components/myOtherlib/index.js"charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
```

My directory structure is:

```
MyApp
- src
  - app
    - index.js
  - index.html
- node_modules
- bower_components
- package.json
- bower.json
- test
- gulpfile.js
```

I am able to access bower_components from index.html but not node_modules.
So I am able to load myOtherlib/index.js but not @mylib/index.js

When I load my index.html I get the error :

GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@mylib/index.js 404 (Not Found)

I am using IntelliJ.

It would be helpful if someone can help me fix this. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: node modules are generally server side... what *exactly* are you trying to access here, from the browser?

Comment: Did you try running an `npm install`?

Comment: I have a library that I want to access inside index.html and use the class inside the library on my front end.

Comment: @fjc yes I ran npm install and I have that custom library installed inside node_ modules. I wanted to know if there is any way to access it from my client side.

Comment: How are you hosting the application? Apache? Is it an Express application? ...?

Comment: @fjc i am running my app using gulp. And my backend server is in Java.

Comment: You simply need to move said file into a location that is available to the browser. You don't *need* a bundler, gulp can be used to move this file over into your build directory.

Comment: my point still stands;  if this is a library that was **intended** for use in the browser, it *should* already copy itself to a directory accessible by the browser.  Without knowing what the library is, it's not really clear why this isn't the case, or even which files would be necessary to move to where.

Answer (score 3):

This is because in frontend(clientside) you are using bower for managing dependencies so that nodemodules will not get included after your successful run of gulp task.You need to modify the gulp task to include node_modules as well.
This is beacuse From your example I came to know that you are using gulp as a task runner ,when you run gulp serve(or task to run the app) will create dist folder in that bower is getting included but not node_modules.All your app is running thru dist folder.

Finally you need to modify the gulpfile.js to include the node_modules.

This will solve your problem.

Then include like this node_modules/dist/lodash.js